# Set custom typeface to all TextView (except ActionBar)

Tags: android, android-typeface

I want to use custom typefaces in my Android application. I use the following method to set custom typeface to all TextView of a  `Activity` or `Fragment`:

```
public static void setTypeFace(Typeface typeFace, ViewGroup parent){
    for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = parent.getChildAt(i);
        if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
            setTypeFace(typeFace, (ViewGroup) v);
        } else if (v instanceof TextView) {
            TextView tv = (TextView) v;
            tv.setPaintFlags(tv.getPaintFlags() | Paint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG);
            tv.setTypeface(typeFace);
        }
    }
}
```

Activity:

```
public class MyActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)getWindow().getDecorView();
        ViewUtil.setTypeFace(tf, vg);
        ...
    }
```

It works well. But unfortunately font of the  ActionBar is also changed. I don't want that..

How can I adapt this method to exclude TextBoxs of the ActionBar?

Thanks!

Comment: define a custom theme with an item android:textViewStyle

Comment: I have updated my question (add MyActivity code).

Comment: and i repeat: google about theming and defaukt widget styles

Comment: if you are a web dev its like a css style but they are applied by default

Comment: @pskink: The problem is I don't want to apply the custom theme on my entire app (so, I don't want my custom font everywhere). It's is possible?

Comment: Is there a way to adapt the setTypeFace() method to exclude TextBox from Action Bar?

Comment: sure you can do it: a ViewGroup containing an ActionBar children must have some fixed id, check it using hierarchyviewer

Comment: @pskink Thanks. The hierarchyviewer tool was unknow to me! It solves my problem (see my answer below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to identified the ID name of the two ActionBar TextBox: `android:id/action_bar_title` and `android:id/action_bar_subtitle`. You can do that with the hierarchyviewer SDK tool (thanks @pskink!).

```
public static void setTypeFace(Typeface typeFace, ViewGroup parent){
    for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View v = parent.getChildAt(i);
        if (v instanceof ViewGroup) {
            setTypeFace(typeFace, (ViewGroup) v);
        } else if (v instanceof TextView) {
            TextView tv = (TextView) v;
            String tvIdName = tv.getResources().getResourceName(tv.getId());
            if (!tvIdName.equals("android:id/action_bar_title") && !tvIdName.equals("android:id/action_bar_subtitle")) {
                if (DO_SUBPIXEL_RENDERING){
                    tv.setPaintFlags(tv.getPaintFlags() | Paint.SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG);
                }
                tv.setTypeface(typeFace);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: great, btw you can just compare integers tv.getId() == R.id.action_bar_(sub)title

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own TextView by Overriding the TextView like this:

```
public class MyTextView extends TextView {

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setType(context);
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        setType(context);
    }

    public MyTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setType(context);
    }

    private void setType(Context context){
        this.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(),
                    "foo.ttf"));

        this.setShadowLayer(1.5f, 5, 5, getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.black_shadow));
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
<com.your.project.package.MyTextView
        android:id="@+id/oppinfo_mtv_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"  
        android:text="Player 1"
        />
```

Comment: It is a solution, but it is not really convenient for my use.